# Why does the triplet state $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\uparrow\downarrow+\downarrow\uparrow)$ have spin 1 and not 0?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, quantum-spin

Don't the spins in the state $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\uparrow\downarrow+\downarrow\uparrow)$ cancel each other so that the total spin is 0 just like for the singlet state $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\uparrow\downarrow-\downarrow\uparrow)$?

Comment: Closely related question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/290472/).

Comment: [Another possible duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/389946/44126).

Comment: Try $S_-$ and $S_+$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This state, like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\uparrow\downarrow -\downarrow\uparrow
\right)$, is an eigenstate of $L_z$ with $m_s=0$.  However, if you act on 
$$
\vert\psi\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\uparrow\downarrow +\downarrow\uparrow
\right)
$$
with $\hat L_+$ or $\hat L_-$ you will not get $0$.  Rather, for instance,
$$
\hat L_+\vert\psi\rangle =\sqrt{2}\uparrow\uparrow
$$
with which is an eigenstate of $L_z$ with eigenvalue $1$.  Since a state
with spin $0$ would be killed by $L_+$ and $L_-$, your state *cannot* have spin-$0$.

In fact since $\hat L_+\hat L_+\vert\psi\rangle=0$ you can deduce that
$\hat L_+\vert\psi\rangle$ is proportional to the spin-$1$ state with $m_s=1$.  Using $L_-\hat L_+\vert\psi\rangle$ will provide you with a state proportional to $\vert\psi\rangle$, which must have the same value of $s=1$.

Comment: If I do a spin measurement I just get $\uparrow\downarrow$ 50% of the measurements for both the singlet and triplet.So what is the physical difference between the singlet $S_0= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\uparrow\downarrow-\downarrow\uparrow)$ and the triplet $T_0 =  \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\uparrow\downarrow+\downarrow\uparrow)$. Are they physically distinguishable?

Comment: If you have an experiment that is sensitive to the relative phase - some sort of interference effects - you could pick up the difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the operator $S^2$ you get $S(S+1)$, so 0 or 2 respectively.

Comment: When you apply $S^2$, you get the state back times 2, which is why the quantum number for its total spin is 1: $1(1+1)=2$.

Comment: @G. Smith Sure, I corrected my answer.